# Gridfs on node native write performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, append, native, gridfs

I'm building a webapp, that use mongo's gridfs in order to store big files(200Mb ~ 500MB).
Files will be uploaded by chunks, in order to not crash the browser.

I've builded a simple demo that does exactly what i want it to.

But it seems to me that writing operation goes slower and slower.
During an upload, when i look at cpu usage it goes up to 100%.

Is there something that i need to be aware of ?
Like append should not be used to heavly.

Is there some kind of study publicly avalable on gridfs write performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's slower and slower is that the driver that i was using
allow append mod, but the way it does it pretty ugly.

On an append request, it will load the file in memory, destroy the record for that file, append the partial file, append it the new part and then save it again.

Which is'nt a real append it's miss leading.
But the community doesn't want to change this.